# Storing pointer value into separate variable

Tags: c++, pointers, char, storage

I have a char* that I would like to store the value of without the new variable being another pointer to the original.

```
char* newVal;

void Foo(char* val)
{
    newVal=val;
    //things happen that change what val represents
}
```

I want newVal to take val and hold what it's value was before other code changes that. So that later in my code, I can compare the two value.

Is this possible? Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you actually want to clone what `val` points to? That's a completely different thing though. Always be clear what exact object you are speaking and thinking about. As an aside, going away to get coffee after posting is *not appreciated*, especially on high-volume tags.

Comment: I want it so that "newVal" is not a pointer to "val" it just carries identical data value.

Comment: @Whelandrew Please see my explanation...

Comment: You mean, you want to clone the object `val` points to and assign the copies address to `newVal`? Being pedantic here is crucial, computers don't generally use fuzzy-logic and guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newVal=val;
```

This would make newVal point to same memory location as val i.e any changes to val would be reflected in newVal also.

In your case it seems that you want newVal to be the copy of val.

```
newVal = new char[strlen(val)+1];  //You can also use malloc.
strcpy(newVal, val);               //newVal and val are separate objects now.
```

Comment: `val` and `newVal` are separate objects, even if they should have the same value. Please do not compound the OPs confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First, take stock of what you want and say so.
Remember that *the plan is not the territory*, a geo-code is not the house, and a pointer and the object it points to are probably completely separate things.

Now, having done that and (I guess) actually wanting the pointed to object copied, the question is *what is it*?
We cannot copy an object if we don't know what it is, so let's suppose it's a 0-terminated string, aka c-string.

In that case, we can create a copy with the Posix `strdup()`-function:

```
char* copy = strdup(val);
```

In case you don't have `strdup`, the implementation looks like this:

```
char* strdup(const char* p) {
    size_t n = strlen(p) + 1;
    char* r = malloc(n);
    if(r) memcpy(r, p, n);
    return r;
}
```

Don't forget to `free` it afterwards.